# Keep rotating Horizontal Scroll view

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have one horizontal scroll view attached with some image views on an activity and I want that when the activity is loaded the images in the horizontal scrollview should move from left to right i.e as like the banner form.

Is this possible in android??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add some image files into the res/drawable folder and use the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>



<ImageView
     android:src="@drawable/pic1"
     android:id="@+id/img1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />


<ImageView
     android:src="@drawable/pic2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
<ImageView
     android:src="@drawable/pic3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
<ImageView
     android:src="@drawable/pic4"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: oh,sorry,I made a mistake ,I will try to find a solution for your question

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's possible. Inside the scrollView class there is a method for setting the position

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollBy(int, int)

that might help you. I know you might want the speed to change and i'm looking if i see a solution for that. I haven't tried this myself just a method i seen in passing

this might also be helpful

scrollTo(int x, int y)

you can maybe in a different thread calculate where the x should be every 30 secs so and then call scrollTo(int x, int y) and pass in the numbers that you want